# Android notification swipe delete disabling

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to disable the swipe delete feature of an android notification from the notifications list in android. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

**Try this code**

```
builder.setOngoing(true); // Cant cancel your notification (except notificationManager.cancel(); )
```

**Above code in Notifcation Builder.**

```
public void DisplayNotification() {

// Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

//icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);

// This intent is fired when notification is clicked
Intent tapIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, tapIntent, 0);

// Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

builder.setOngoing(true); // Cant cancel your notification (except NotificationManger.cancel(); )

// Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
builder.setContentTitle("Notifications Title");

// Content text, which appears in smaller text below the title
builder.setContentText("Your notification content here.");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Will display the notification in the notification bar
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

**Cancel Notification**

```
public void cancelNotification() {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); // Notification ID to cancel
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: You can put clear notification code anywhere as far as you are aware of notification ID.

Comment: How to detect left and right swipe of notification

Answer (score 19):

you can mark your Notification as an 'ongoing' notification.

--> [Notification.Builder setOngoing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29)

Comment: i believe that's the best way of achieving such a goal.

Answer (score 5):

```
notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
```

not allow to cancel notification by swipe.