# Notifications swipable but not removing onclick android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to create notifications that you can swipe or remove from the notifications menu, but if you press on it it stays there (and opens the app).

I've looked into some questions, but they didn't resolve my problem:
[Android notification swipe delete disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795336/android-notification-swipe-delete-disabling) , the not deleting on a click
[Remove notification after clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120821/remove-notification-after-clicking) , this has the swipe-delete feature.

So something in between of that.

Groetjes,

Arend-Jan

Comment: did you try this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)

Comment: you want your notification to stay there even if your app is opened?

Comment: @ootinii Thats exactly what I needed, `.setAutoCancel(false)` did the job.